# Why am I getting 'UnsuccessfulCommandException' when using TesseractOCR in cPanel?

Tags: yii2, ocr, cpanel, tesseract

thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\UnsuccessfulCommandException
Error! The command did not produce any output.
i am getting an error while using this vendor for image to text convert in cpanel.its working on my local pc but not in cpanel?

its seems its not getting proper env variable path in cpanel.

Comment: did you check does your hosting provider have tesseract ocr cli software?
Try `tesseract --version` in the command line terminal

Comment: Hi  DarkShade,Thanks for your reply its not install in cpanel sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr.can you please suggest me.

Comment: Is `tesseract --version` command returned tesseract version? if not returned, are you not installed tesseract OCR

Comment: ok i have tried its nothing return.how can i install tesseract in cpanel?